# как закрыть диалоговое окно в windows использую метод в Python для теста автоматизации

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть проблема: написал тест автоматизации на Python для сайта. И есть одно из условий для выполнения теста: кликнуть на элемент страницы, который открывает диалоговое окно в Windows, в этом окне выбрать файл для загрузки на страницу сайта, закрыть диалоговое окно в Windows.
Кликнуть и открыть окно в Windows получилось, не знаю как выбрать файл и закрыть это окно.

Comment: Мне кажется Пайтоном трудновато взаимодействовать с графическими элементами. Для автоматизации задач в виндоус, связанных с окнами и т.д. я бы советовал програмку Autoit (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). Создаете скриптик и он все, что вам надо делает, нажимает на кнопки, выбирает, эмулирует клавиатуру, мышку и т.д. И есть конечно же огромное количество уже готовых скриптов для нее.

Comment: @Michael автор вероятно (не указано) selenium webdriver использует (чтобы потестировать сайт, тыкая на разные элементы в браузере), который поддерживает посылку нажатия клавиш—автору следует текущий код привести. Если сервер тестировать, то лучше http-запросы, используя requests модуль посылать (вообще без GUI: без диалогов, браузеров). Если произвольную GUI программу, то есть pywinauto, pyautogui модули и другие. [Interact with other programs using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14288177/4279)

Comment: Спасибо большое, за ответ. Попробую с  Autoit  выполнить.

Comment: Может кто подскажет как загрузить файл png.на страницу сайта используя Python 3.5?

Comment: @jfs Очень интересные штуки! Сам гляну тоже! :)